# How to write handlebars if condition for integer values

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

How to write handlebars if condition for integer values. I've tried this below code but not working.

```
{{#if (eq number '1')}}
        number 1    
{{else}}                
      another number    
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `{{if (eq a b)}}` helpers equivalent Javascript code is `if (a === b)`, you can provide variables or values directly.

```
{{#if (eq number 1)}}
        number 1    
{{else}}                
      another number    
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that you have defined a helper function named "eq"? As far as I know "eq" is not a standard function in Handlebars.

Comment: @PeterBerggreen Yes. You are right, I thought OP already got that helper. I personally use awesome [ember-truth-helpers addon](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

The Mandrill mail service supports Handlebars and here it is possible to use "backticks" to evaluate an logical expression in a #if block:

```
{{#if `number < 0`}}
  negative
{{elseif `number == 42`}}
  the answer is 42
{{else}}
  positive and not 42
{{/if}}
```

I don't know if this possible in general, but you should try it out. 
It works fine for me.